# Watch as I pass you by, Hurrah!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I'm usually on top, or behind a bar

Some sly-sounding people will throw me far

So watch as I pass you by, Hurrah!

---

I can be sweet yet cold you see

And few will want to count on me

---

**Question**

What am I and can you explain all seven clues?

**Note**

You are looking for a single word with five distinct meanings.

**Hint 1**

> Because there are five meanings and yet I've talked about seven clues, I should perhaps say that three of the clues are used to pin down just one of the meanings. It made for a better rhyme!

**Hint 2**

> The three clues that combine to identify a single meaning are: *I'm usually on top. Some sly-sounding people will throw me far.*

Comment: The "three clues" referenced in hint two are only two clues? Unless that itself is somehow a clue?

Comment: @Mohirl  - The three clues, (1) I'm usually on top (2) Some sly-sounding people (3) will throw me far. Note: Clue 2 is not a clue to identify "me". It identifies a certain type of person that should lead you to "me". Clue 2 is the most cryptic of the clues. I expect solvers to understand this last of all. All other clues are more direct.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I was reading the last two as one clue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proposing this for consideration:

> **float**

I'm usually on top, some sly-sounding people will throw me far

> a float rises up and anglers (angle as an ulterior motive) may cast their lines with a float

or behind a bar

> a float is a pool of coins a bar uses to give exact change  - credit @Stiv

I can be sweet yet cold you see

> a float is a soft drink with a scoop of ice-cream

So watch as I pass you by, Hurrah!

> a float is a decorated vehicle in a parade

And few will want to count on me

> a computer program counts with int data types and not floats  - counted on @Stiv for this

Comment: Congratulations, you have the correct word! Just needs a little tidying up (1) Your first two answers both refer to the same object as mentioned in hint two.  (2) "behind a bar", and "I can be sweet yet cold" have two *different* meanings - the second is correct. (3)  Many people *do* count on short-term loans so that doesn't work IMO. Do you have any computer knowledge?

Comment: I think the two hints you're missing are rot13('sybng' nf va n cbby bs pbvaf gb ranoyr phfgbzref gb erprvir gurve pbeerpg punatr, naq sybngvat cbvag ahzoref, juvpu pna yrnq gb harkcrpgrq erfhygf va pnyphyngvbaf) - nice solve though :) +1 (comment rewritten to avoid spoiler!)

Comment: @Stiv - Yes and yes. What would you use  rot13( vafgrnq bs sybngf vs lbh ner pbhagvat, r.t. va n *sbe ybbc*?)

Comment: @Stiv, thanks for the right explanations - and not for the first time!

Comment: Guess I should encrypt this? still trying to figure this site out... rot13( V jnf whfg svtugvat pbzchgre sybngf abg fhzzvat ng jbex lrfgreqnl. Fubhyq unir unq guvf bar! V thrffrq fbzr pbyq qevax ohg qvqa'g guvax bs sybng..)

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking :

> Ice

I'm usually on top, or behind a bar

> icing on top, or ice behind the bar (for drinks)

Some sly-sounding people will throw me far

> This is a little bit of a stretch, but i googled for this as "throw some ice"

So watch as I pass you by, Hurrah!

> The ice flows, the last hurrah.

I can be sweet yet cold you see

> ice cream.

And few will want to count on me

> ice melts, is a temporary state (at least on earth).

Comment: Paradoxically, you are getting warm!   However I don't understand "The ice flows, the last hurrah."  Also, the word I'm looking for has 5 different meanings - see hint. I think ice has only one.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I missed the distinct meanings. My thinking on "The ice flows, the last hurrah.", is when the ice breaks/melts say on a lake in the spring. this season is the last hurrah of ice fishing.

Comment: It's interesting to me that you are in a way skirting around parts of the puzzle. However pursuing that thought will probably just confuse you until you see the final answer!

Answer (score 3):

Could be

> STAR

I'm usually on top, or behind a bar

> Star on top of a Christmas tree - Star Behind the Bar? (Came up on Google)

Some sly-sounding people will throw me far

> Ninja (sneaky) throwing stars

So watch as I pass you by, Hurrah!

> Star gazing - stars moving across the sky

I can be sweet yet cold you see

> [Starfruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carambola) - [Cold stars](https://www.space.com/12714-coldest-failed-stars-brown-dwarfs-wise.html#:%7E:text=Y%20dwarfs%20are%20the%20coldest,cooler%20than%20the%20human%20body.)

And few will want to count on me

> Count your lucky stars

Title

> Passed by “So” from the corresponding line. Making (get ready)...Watch as I pass So by, Hurrah! - Capital letters spell WISH. Like in wish upon a star. I could be way off though.

Comment: Nice idea but not my intended answer. I'll add a hint soon. Note: You are right to look for a single word.  P.S. Star behind a bar is a little unconvincing!  Also I've never seen stargazers shouting Hurrah! but you never know.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly

> Cream ?

Though I'm struggling so far with most of the clues

I'm usually on top, or behind a bar

> Cream rises to the top; you might have whipped cream behind a bar

Some sly-sounding people will throw me far
???

So watch as I pass you by, Hurrah!
????

I can be sweet yet cold you see

> Ice cream is sweet

And few will want to count on me
???

Comment: I don't think cream has five meanings.

Comment: @Mohirl - It is not cream but you are definitely making progress here.

Comment: @LakshaySura You'd be surprised. I can easily get 5 meanings, just not 5 that fit! (e.g. top of milk; ice cream; to skim off the top; the band; ointment)

Comment: @Mohirl  - Yes, you have the right line of thinking!  Later today I'll add another hint that may help.